# jQuery cross domain iframe scripting

Tags: jquery, cross-domain

I am trying to access the DOM of an iframe that loads an external URL. Of course that I get a "Permission denied for" error due to cross domain security. How can I make this work? I saw something done with json (but I can not get a json string from my external source) and something done with HTML5 postmessage.

you can see it live at :
http://jsfiddle.net/QPBvJ/

The code is:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
     $('#get').live('click', function() {

        var currentIFrame = $('#frameDemo');
        currentIFrame.contents().find("a").css("background-color","#BADA55");

        alert ("done")
    });
    });

<iframe src="http://api.jquery.com/" width="80%" height="600" id='frameDemo'></iframe>
<button id="get">Get</button>
```

What would the the easiest way to make this work.
Thank you

Comment: You can check this post with a related to the cross domain requests: **[Loading cross domain html page with jQuery AJAX](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17299796/2247494)**

Answer (score 28, accepted):

There is no way to make this work. Unless, the foreign domain you try to access supports a procedure like [C.O.R.S](http://hacks.mozilla.org/2009/07/cross-site-xmlhttprequest-with-cors/), [JSONP](http://www.ajaxlines.com/ajax/stuff/article/jquery_ajax_cross_domains_using_jsonp_getjson.php) or [postMessage](http://ajaxian.com/archives/cross-window-messaging-with-html-5-postmessage).

There are a few exceptions (like always):

If you're dealing with a WebApp for instance, you can tell your users that they have to grant access to `cross-domain-calls`.

In Gecko/Firefox for instance, you can call

```
netscape.security.PrivilegeManager.enablePrivilege('UniversalBrowserRead')
```

which enables the browser to access foreign domains via `ajax/iframes`. In this scenario, an user has to set

```
signed.applets.codebase_principal_support
```

to `true` under `about:config` to make this work.

In the `Internet Explorers` of this world, there is a setting called something like `allow cross-domain access` deeply hidden in the `security` tab, which must be set to `enable`.

`Chrome` allows cross-domain calls with a commandline argument:

```
chrome.exe --disable-web-security
```

Comment: Ok, thanx for the info. I am working on this, it should work.

Comment: Here you can find some info related to the cross domain requests: **[Loading cross domain html page with jQuery AJAX](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17299796/2247494)**