# Cannot get the contents of an iframe w/ jQuery

Tags: jquery, iframe

I'm inserting an iframe to display another website's content in mine, and I'd like to clean it up first. So I tried to use `$('iframe').contents`, but the return is undefined, while `$('iframe')` works like a charm. Is there some kind of cross site security here ?

Bonus question : how should I clean the page then ? I just need `div#main`, not the rest. I'm using an iframe so I can get the original styling.

Thanks for your time

Comment: Refer this [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/364952/jquery-javascript-accessing-contents-of-an-iframe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/364952/jquery-javascript-accessing-contents-of-an-iframe)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there some kind of cross site security here?

Yes, the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

There aren't many ways around it - I once used PHP to fetch the contents of the target webpage and write them locally, but that was quite a specific thing (and I owned both domains).

Take a look at this question: [jQuery cross domain iframe scripting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3083112/jquery-cross-domain-iframe-scripting)

Comment: Getting the content of the target page is actually not an issue and very easy to do with ruby/nokogiri. I try not to use iframes, but in this case, it was useful in order to have a nice rendering without putting effort in it. Anyway, thanks to you & Linus below.

Answer (score 2):

It's called [Same-Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). Basically, you can't use javascript to interact with pages from another domain (protocol, domain and port must all match).