# Chrome userscript error: "Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame"

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, iframe, greasemonkey, userscripts

```
// the iframe of the div I need to access
var iframe = document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")[2];
var innerDoc = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;

// resize 'player' in the iframe
innerDoc.getElementById('player').width = "1000px";
innerDoc.getElementById('player').height = "650px";
```

Running in a userscript for this url: http://www.free-tv-video-online.me/player/sockshare.php?id=24DA6EAA2561FD60

**Why does Chrome come out with this error and fail the script?:**

```
Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL http://www.sockshare.com/embed/24DA6EAA2561FD60 
from frame with URL http://www.free-tv-video-online.me/player/sockshare.php?id=24DA6EAA2561FD60. 
Domains, protocols and ports must match.
```

*(I'm only a basic Javascript user)*

---

Final code, many thanks to the answerer:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name       Resize
// @include    http://www.free-tv-video-online.me/player/sockshare.php*
// @include    http://www.sockshare.com/*
// ==/UserScript==

if (!(window.top === window.self)) {
    var player = document.getElementById('player');
    setSize(player);
}

function setSize(player) {
    player.style.setProperty("width", "1000px");
    player.style.setProperty("height", "650px");
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's true that ordinary javascript cannot access iframe content, that's on a different domain, for security reasons.  **However**, this by no means stops userscripts in Chrome, Tampermonkey or Greasemonkey.

You can process iframed content in a userscript because Chrome (and Firefox) process iframe'd pages just as if they were the main page.  Accounting for that, scripting such pages is a snap.

For example, suppose you have this page at ***domain_A.com***:

```
<html>
<body>
    <iframe src="http://domain_B.com/SomePage.htm"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

If you set your `@match` directives like this:

```
// @match http://domain_A.com/*
// @match http://domain_B.com/*
```

Then your script will run twice -- once on the main page and once on the iframe as though it were a standalone page.

So if your script was like this:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name  _Test iFrame processing in Chrome and Tampermonkey
// @match http://domain_A.com/*
// @match http://domain_B.com/*
// ==/UserScript==

if (/domain_A\.com/i.test (document.location.href) ) {
    //Main page
    document.body.style.setProperty ("background", "lime", "important");
}
else {
    //iFrame
    document.body.style.setProperty ("background", "pink", "important");
}
```

You would see the main page in lime-green, and the iframed page in pink.

Alternatively, you can test like this:

```
if (window.top === window.self) {
    //--- Code to run when page is the main site...
}
else {
    //--- Code to run when page is in an iframe...
}
```

---

---

As you discovered (per comment on another answer), you can [disable the same origin policy on Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3102819/331508). **Don't do this!**  You will leave yourself open to all kinds of shenanigans set up by bad people.  In addition to evil sites, many nominally "good" sites -- that allow users to post content -- could potentially track, hack, or spoof you.

Comment: Oh wow, that worked perfectly. Put my final code in the OP, thank you kindly!

Answer (score 1):

For security reasons your browser won't allow you to access javascript in an iframe from another domain.

See the top answer here:

[jQuery cross domain iframe scripting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3083112/jquery-cross-domain-iframe-scripting)

Comment: Oh, I see. I misunderstood the error (and the other explanations for it). You've somehow made it simpler to understand :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6083677/1053937 - found a way of disabling that security option :)

Comment: Not expecting your users to do that though are you?

Comment: This answer is not correct for userscripts.  They have a mechanism to work around this cross-domain restriction, and **without** compromising security.

Comment: Rhodesian, as I said it is for a **userscript**