# Can't invoke function in a same-domain iframe in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, iframe, greasemonkey

I write code for Greasemonkey and I have an iframe without a `src` in which I add code like this:

```
 var appendToHead = function(iframe, content) {
    var doc = iframe[0].contentWindow.document;
    var element = doc.createElement('script');
    element.type = 'text/javascript';
    element.text = content;
    doc.head.appendChild(element);
};
```

I see in Firebug that the function is added in the iframe. But when I try to get them, EG 
`frames[0].contentWindow.functionName` I get `undefined` and still see them in debugger.

Before I used Greasemonkey this approach worked well. How can invoke these functions?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I access an iframe's javascript from a userscript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11638595/how-do-i-access-an-iframes-javascript-from-a-userscript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [How do I access an iframe's javascript from a userscript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11645666/331508).

You would invoke the function like: `frames[0].functionName();`, but **it must be from injected code**, not the Greasemonkey script scope.  (Except that `@grant none` *might* work in some cases.)

You may also need a delay, depending. Post a full working example of what you are doing.

Comment: So without @grant none there is no way i can invoke function's from Greasemonkey script scope?  And why need a delay?

Comment: And if i choose not to use api with grant none, how can i load big css files(if not to do big string)?

Comment: That's right, there is no way you can invoke the functions from Greasemonkey script scope without `@grant none` -- which I don't recommend.  Inject the code.  The CSS bit is not clear. Might need to ask another question for that.

Comment: i use GM_addStyle(GM_getResourceText(name)) on what to replace GM_getResourceText?

Comment: Don't replace `GM_getResourceText`; just inject the part of your code that calls iframe code.  And before you ask, see ["How to call Greasemonkey's GM_ functions from code that must run in the target page scope"](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14255440/331508).