# Access an element inside a dynamically-created, cross-domain iFrame?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, cross-domain, greasemonkey

I want to access an element inside an iFrame, but because of the way the iFrame is being called, I am not succeeding.

[This is the target page (www1.k9webprotection.com/...).](http://www1.k9webprotection.com/get-k9-web-protection-free)

The iframe is on a different subdomain:

```
<iframe src="http://license.k9webprotection.com/..." ...></iframe>
```

Setting a timeout or an event listener for when the iframe is loaded, did not help.

Comment: Is it on the same domain, or do you control both domains?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this looks like spam to promote the website being linked to

Comment: For interactions between the main page and the iframed one, see [this kind of technique](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11769066/331508).

Comment: @chiliNUT, linking to a target page is a very good thing for a Greasemonkey/Tampermonkey/userscript question.  It is not spam and the OP's post could hardly be seen as boosting that site in any SEO-useful way. (Also note that Stack Exchange uses `rel="nofollow"` on all such links.)

Comment: (some) code has since been added since that comment. The original post was only the first 2 lines. A post with very little description, zero code, and a link to an unrelated offsite page looks like spam.

Comment: @chiliNUT, I edited the question after 100 seconds of analyzing the target page.  Sure, it's a poor question. But, the offsite page is completely relevant in a userscript context like this one.

Answer (score 1):

Both documents are placed on different (sub)domains, by default they are not able to interact via javascript.

You must set the `domain` of both documents to the same value.

Put this somewhere in the `<head/>` of both pages:

```
<script  type="text/javascript">
document.domain='k9webprotection.com'
</script>
```

...then wait for the `onload`-event of the iframe and you should be able to access the document inside the iframe from the parent page(and vice versa).

Sample-Script for GreaseMonkey(simply overwrites the body of the iframe):

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        k9
// @namespace   k9
// @include     http://www1.k9webprotection.com/get-k9-web-protection-free
// @include     http://license.k9webprotection.com/license.jsp*
// @version     1
// @grant       none
// ==/UserScript==


document.domain= 'k9webprotection.com';
if(self===top){  
  try{
    $('iframe.getk9iframe').load(function(){
       $('body',this.contentDocument)
        .text('gotcha')
          .css({background:'red',fontSize:'3em'});
    });
    alert("I'm the document in the top-window");
  }
  catch(e){}
}
```

Comment: Added a sample-script, works for me in Firefox