# Greasemonkey script for page with cross-domain iframe

Tags: javascript, cross-domain, greasemonkey

I would like to implement JavaScript that modifies the content of input field which is in `iframe` loaded from another domain ([this is the site](http://www.ah.nl/over-ah/services/mobiel/online-opwaarderen)).

Difficulties:

- Somehow jQuery is loaded with a delay, so I had to use `setTimeout()` to make sure that jQuery becomes available.
- The only `iframe` is loaded from another domain, causing `Permission denied to access property 'document'` when I try to use `iframe.contentWindow.document` from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14451358/how-to-pick-element-inside-iframe-using-document-getelementbyid).
- I tried to apply cross-domain technique which is provided in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28309576/access-an-element-inside-a-dynamically-created-cross-domain-iframe), but it does not work.
- IDs of the elements contain semicolons, so one should use advise from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5552462/handling-colon-in-element-id-with-jquery).

Script:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name    ah.nl
// @include http://www.ah.nl/over-ah/services/mobiel/*
// @include https://ezpay.liquix.eu/WebReloadSolution/*
// @grant   none
// @namespace   http://www.example.com/gmscripts/
// ==/UserScript==

document.domain= 'ah.nl';
if (self === top) {  
    setTimeout(function() {
            try {
                $('iframe').load(function() {
                    console.log("Start " + this.src);
                    var inputs = $('input', this.contentDocument);
                    console.log("Got " + inputs.length);
                    // Below does not work:
                    //inputs.find('#orderForm\\:msisdnConfirm, #orderForm\\:msisdn').val('1234567890');
                });
            } catch(e) {
                console.log(e);
            }
    }, 1000);
}
```

Produces:

```
Start https://ezpay.liquix.eu/WebReloadSolution/index.jsp?merchant=ahnl&language=nl&mode=reload&productCode=1
Got 1
```

The reason why there is one element is that `<input>` element is found in top document.

Could anyone provide a working Greasemonkey solution?

FF 43.0.1, Greasemonkey v3.8.

Comment: Since the page and iframe are on completely separate domains, that approach is not going to work.  Use `postMessage` to communicate between the 2 instances of your script.  See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11489451) for an example.

Comment: [This example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11774184/) may be a better one for your case.  You can also communicate between instances using `GM_setValue()`, but this is a little messy in FF+GM. (Chrome + TM makes it easier)