# How to get element's id in click event inside an iframe?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<iframe id="myiframe" src="doc.html">
    <button id="btn1"></button><!-- how to get this id? -->
</iframe>
```

```js
$('#myiframe').on('click', function () {
    alert(this.id);
});
```

I want it to alert "btn1".

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to pick element inside iframe using document.getElementById](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14451358/how-to-pick-element-inside-iframe-using-document-getelementbyid)

Comment: If you use `<iframe src="doc.html"><button></button></iframe>`, the iframe will load "doc.html" instead of the button.

Comment: doc.html are in my server, but i need get your id.

Answer (score 0):

No. There is no way to do this for security reasons.

The only way to communicate between an iframe and the current page is if the url in the iframe already contains some javascript and updates the iframe url. The iframe then put some data in the url that the page can retrieve.

If the target of the iframe does not belong to you, this is impossible.

Answer (score 0):

See [jQuery cross domain iframe scripting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3083112/jquery-cross-domain-iframe-scripting) for a complex workaround which could possibly make this work.

This is not recommended though; the best approach would be to rearchitect the document and try to solve a different problem. For example, you could request the remote content via an ajax call and insert it into your document.

For example, using [jQuery.load](http://api.jquery.com/load/):

```
$(".target-element").load("doc.html", null, function() {
    var id = $(".target-element").find("#btn").attr("id");
});
```

Answer (score -1):

this.id isn't valid I think, it would also be technically selecting the wrong id(#myIframe)

you'd want something like `this.children().attr('id');`

Comment: `this.id` is fine. Only *issues* are - it is simple and it isn't *jQuery*.

Comment: BTW, you should make *statements* in your *answer*, because this isn't a discussion forum. Discussions goes in **comments**, not via answers.