# Adding new elements to existing Iframe by JS

Tags: javascript, firefox, dom, iframe, firefox-addon

I'm trying to add some html elements inside a iframe, to personalize a site. I'm building a browser extension, so there is no cross-domain problem. I have the iframe:

```
<iframe id="container" src="http://www.google.com">
    <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
</iframe>
```

and then, when the document is already loaded, I create the element and insert it... But it is never shown in the iframe. But I am allowed to get an iframe-existent element and to change it's properties. So, I have access to the elements but not for create new ones? Why?

```
var ifr = document.querySelector("#container");
var ifrDoc = ifr.contentWindow || ifr.contentDocument;
    if (ifrDoc.document) ifrDoc = ifrDoc.document;

var elem = ifrDoc.createElement("div");
    elem.innerHTML = "Demo Box";
    elem.style.width = "50px";
    elem.style.height = "50px";
    elem.style.position = "absolute";
    elem.style.background = "red";

ifrDoc.body.appendChild(elem);
```

Here a JSFiddle demo to understand the problem (remember extensions have another privileges): http://jsfiddle.net/TH48e/40/

Any idea?

Comment: Why do you think that HTML content can be inserted in Google.com? Can you link somewhere where it says that? I don't see why the Same Origin Policy would be any different when creating Browser extensions.

Comment: Extensions can do that. E.g. Greasemonkey

Comment: Are you trying to create a Browser extension or User Script?

Comment: What scope are you running this code from?

Comment: The chrome window (Firefox)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After your clarification in comments:

```
var ifr = gBrowser.selectedBrowser.contentDocument.getElementById('container')
```

Dont do that `.contentWindow` then get the `document` from that, its useless redundant etc.

Also dont do `querySelector` if you want to just get something by `id` anyways, huge speed difference, `getElementById` is much faster.

Also don't do `.innerHTML` the addon approvers won't accept it because it leads to security issues. Do `.textContent`.

Your fiddle will not work because:

1. You can't do cross frame communication
2. I'm not sure but I think: `createElement` is a "native" function in javascript so reserved in away although it is `document.createElement` but ya

This fiddle works, the `rawr` function is undefined in body, I'm not sure why so i moved the script to the document:

http://jsfiddle.net/TH48e/43/

```
<script>
function createElementMY(){
    var doc = document.getElementById('container');

    var ifrDoc = doc.contentDocument;


    var elem = ifrDoc.createElement("div");
    elem.textContent = 'Test';
    ifrDoc.body.appendChild(elem);
}
</script>
<iframe id="container" src="data:text/html,rawr"></iframe>
<button onclick="createElementMY()">Click me!</button>
```

Comment: Hey! Thanks you a lot for all the explanation! But I still have the problem. In your demo you are using an "empty" iframe, not linked to any external url. I updated the demo (http://jsfiddle.net/TH48e/45/) to work with external sources and it throws the erro: Permission denied to access property 'document'

Comment: In content code you will get that error. But from privelaged scope (chrome scope) you won't get that error. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3083112/jquery-cross-domain-iframe-scripting