# jQuery prepend to dynamically created elements (which I didn't create, iframe)

Tags: jquery, html, append, prepend

I use third-party player which creates dynamically after page load.

I try to add elements to it with jQuery .prepend() but nothing happens.

Initial player look like:

```
<div id="player"></div>
```

After page load Player Script modify the player and it become looks like:

```
<iframe id="player">
  <div id="play_button"></div>
  <div id="settings_button"></div>
</iframe>
```

Then plugin call event "onPlayerReady" and player starts playback. After this I try to add `<div id="ad_icon">AD</div>` to div `<div id="settings_button"></div>` with such code:

```
function onPlayerReady(){
    console.log($("#settings_button").length); // returns '0'
    $("#settings_button").prepend("<div id='ad_icon'>AD</div>");
}
```

but nothing happens. Seems like `div` with `id=settings_button` doesn't exist for jQuery. Console.log `$("#settings_button").length` returns `0`. I see new elements in the page code but jQuery returns nothing.

Any ideas how can I use .prepend() function with dynamically created elements in iframe (which were created not by me)?

Comment: Under what event are you trying to run your code? Are you certain the `#settings_button` exists in the DOM when you run it?

Comment: where is your `prepend` code? is it executing after the div is modified by your `third-party player`?

Comment: Yes, I call `prepend` after player starts playing.

Comment: Is it on same document context? e.g, not set inside iframe?

Comment: check `console.log($("#settings_button").length)`

Comment: Not inside iframe – I call it in js function after player starts playing

Comment: @PranavCBalan it's `0` ;( What I need to do with this?

Comment: So at time you call it, element doesn't exist. Hard to help you more without seeing any minimalistic sample replicating your issue

Comment: @KirMazur :  can you reproduce the problem in stack snippet??

Comment: Updated my question with more code.

Comment: Guys could the problem be because of iframe? The player is iframe based and seems like I try to catch elements inside of it :(

Answer (score 1):

You should use .contents() to access elements inside the iframe.
So the code will be :

```
$("#player").contents().find("#settings_button").prepend("<div id='ad_icon'>AD</div>");
```

Comment: Great, answer! Thanks! Forgot about .contents(). Unfortunately the frame is cross-origin, so I still can't get an info. Do you know some other options?

Comment: Well according to the Google results, unfortunately no without change the browser settings ;_;

Comment: maybe you want to read : [another StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3083112/jquery-cross-domain-iframe-scripting)

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind events using event delegation,

As your elements are added at runtime, you need to put this event delegation,

```
$(document).on('click', '#settings_button', function(){
          $(this).prepend("<div id='ad_icon'>AD</div>");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code,

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#player').bind('DOMNodeInserted', function (event) {
        $("#settings_button").prepend("<div id='ad_icon'>AD</div>");
    });
});
```

Comment: This would prepend a new div **on each** new inserted DOM (whatever it is) and btw, because it will insert a new node using prepend() method, it would throw a stack error (recursive issue). I guess `$('#player').one('DOMNodeInserted', function (event) {...});` would fix it but using observer is bad practice usually. That's said, this is for sure more relevant answer than the two other ones already posted