# jquery detect change in display or visibility

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way for me to detect if the style attribute of a class changes, for example, a change in display or visibility?

The situation I have is that I have a Podio webform embedded on my site via `iframe` and that has a hidden thank you message in `.webforms__success-message > p` and I want to scroll to the success message when it appears on the page.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure you can even get to the content of a remote URL in an iframe via jquery, I could be wrong though but the security implications would be horrendous!

Comment: I am able to trigger a DOM event using the class so I would guess yes

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3083112/jquery-cross-domain-iframe-scripting

Comment: @SandraWillford I flagged this as duplicate, take a look at the previous discussion.

Comment: @Dale is on point - you can't access an iFrame's content via javascript.  Browsers prevent this for security purposes.

Comment: If the form belongs to him on his domain he can.

Comment: The form does not belong to OP.  It's from **Podio**, which is a service on another domain.

Comment: @SandraWillford Sorry, looks like you'll need to think of another approach!

Comment: @cale_b I've never been refered to as on point before, thank you :)

Comment: Have you looked at an integration that doesn't use the iframe? For example, have you read the Podio api developer docs?

Comment: @SandraWillford what do you mean by "I am able to trigger a DOM event using the class"

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend VueJS instead of jQuery. It's faster because it uses a virtual dom and it doesn't have to traverse the dom in order to detect changes. You simply create an action and then emit that action as an event. Then you can call whichever jQuery functions you would like.

```
<div id="app">
   <iframe v-show="isShowing" src="http://www.weather.gov/" 
        frameborder="0"
        ></iframe>
  <button @click="isShowing ^= true">Click Me</button>
</div>
```

CSS

```
iframe {
  display:block;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-left: 200px;
  width:850px;
  height:300px;
}
```

JS

```
var vue = new Vue({
  el:"#app",
  data: {
    isShowing:false,
  }
})
```

check out this [Codepen](http://codepen.io/michael_coder/pen/WReNNm)

Comment: Not in an iFrame...